# Moving character efficiently on a row

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, doubly-linked-list

Given input `(items = 6, position = 3)`

creates a row of `6 items` and a character positioned on `item 3` `{0,1,2,[3],4,5}`

A call to `left()` moves the character **two** positions to the left and the `item at position 3 is removed` `{0,[1],2,4,5}`

The next call to `right()` moves the character two positions to the right and the `item at position 1 is removed` `{0,2,[4],5}`

Then calling `position()` method now should return `4`.

The character will not move to the left or right if no items are present so no need to implement that.

```
public class MyClass {
    int position;
    int[] items;
    public MyClass(int n, int position) {
        this.position = position;
        items = new int[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            items[i] = i;
        }
    }
}

public void left() {
    int p = this.position;
    items[p] = -1;
    for(int z=0; z<2;) {
        p--;
        int value = arr[p];
        if(value != -1) {
            z++;
        }
    }
    this.position = p;
}

public void right() {
    int p = this.position;
    items[p] = -1;
    for(int z=0; z<2;) {
        p++;
        int value = arr[p];
        if(value != -1) {
            z++;
        }
    }
    this.position = p;
}

public int position() {
    return arr[position];
}
```

This code works perfectly for small inputs, but I am getting performance errors when the input is large.

How to implement this efficiently? I don't have test case details for the error related to performance errors.

Comment: What exactly is a "performance error"? What are the restrictions on what you are allowed to use?

Comment: @UnholySheep, restrictions are not mentioned so we can use anything that can run faster. Regarding performance error, my code uses a for loop and breaks conditionally, so the loop runs unnecessarily if input values are very large and if we do multiple left and right operations. So my approach is not correct.

Comment: In that case a doubly linked list, as suggested by Abhinav, is most likely the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it already has been pointed outed both in the comments and the answer by *@AbhinavMathur*, in order to improve performance you need to implement [*Doubly linked list*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) data structure.

Note that it's mandatory to create your *own implementation* that will maintain a reference to the *current node*. Attempt to utilize an implementation built-in in the JDK in place of the `items` array will not buy you anything because the advantage of the fast deletion will be nullified by the cost of iteration (in order to reach the element at position `n`, `LinkedList` needs to crawl through the `n` elements starting from the *head*, and this operation has a liner time complexity).

Methods `left()`, `right()` and `position()` will have the following outcome:

- `left()` - in case when the *previous* node (denoted as `prev` in the code) associated with `current` is not `null`, and in tern its *previous node* exists, the *current node* will be dereferenced (i.e. next and previous nodes associated with the `current` node will be linked with each other), and the variable `current` would be assigned to the `prev` of the *previous node*, i.e. `current.prev.prev`. Time complexity **O(1)**.
- `right()` - in case when the *next* node (denoted as `next` in the code) associated with `current` is not `null`, and in tern its *next node* exists, the *current node* will be dereferenced in a way that has been described above, and the variable `current` would be assigned to the `next` of the *next node*, i.e. `current.next.next`. Time complexity **O(1)**.
- `position()` - will return a value of the `current` node. Time complexity **O(1)**.

That's how it might look like:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Node current; // a replacement for both position and items fields

    public MyClass(int n, int position) {
        Node current = new Node(0, null, null); // initialing the head node
        if (position == 0) {
            this.current = current;
        }
    
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) { // initialing the rest past of the linked list
            Node nextNode = new Node(i, current, null);
            current.setNext(nextNode);
            current = nextNode;
        
            if (position == i) {
                this.current = current;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void left() { // removes the current node and sets the current to the node 2 position to the left (`prev` of the `prev` node)
        if (current.prev == null || current.prev.prev == null) {
            return;
        }
        
        Node prev = current.prev;
        Node next = current.next;
        prev.setNext(next);
        next.setPrev(prev);
        this.current = prev.prev;
    }

    public void right() { // removes the current node and sets the current to the node 2 position to the right (`next` of the `next` node)
        if (current.next == null || current.next.next == null) {
            return;
        }

        Node prev = current.prev;
        Node next = current.next;
        prev.setNext(next);
        next.setPrev(prev);
        this.current = next.next;
    }

    public int position() {
        return current.getValue();
    }
    
    public static class Node {
        private int value;
        private Node prev;
        private Node next;

        public Node(int value, Node prev, Node next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.prev = prev;
            this.next = next;
        }

        // getters and setters
    }
}
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rFs)

Comment: In my requirement, for input {0,1,2,[3],4,5}, so if the current node is 3, calling left will move to 1, and node 3 should be removed. so the nodes becomes {0,[1],2,4,5}. In the solution you provided, the call to method left will become {0,[1],3,4,5}, so there is a bug in the code, Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @learner  Sorry, I've misunderstood the example. Now, it removes the `current` no node and then moves position by `2`. Here is an [*Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rFs) `3` -> `left()` -> `1` -> `right()` -> `4`

Answer (score 0):

Using an array, you're setting the "removed" elements as `-1`; repeatedly skipping them in each traversal causes the performance penalty.

Instead of an array, use a [doubly linked list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/doubly-linked-list/). Each removal can be easily done in `O(1)` time, and each left/right operation would only require shifting the current pointer by 2 nodes.